# How to update SQLite on Mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rvm

I'm getting the error "Could not find gem 'sqlite3-ruby (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile." after trying to run the command $ rails server.

Using RVM, gemset is 1.8.7-p334, Rails 3.0.0 on Mac 10.6.6, SQLite version 3.6.12

Trying to match the same setup as a Rails training video. Searched Stackoverflow, Google, RVM manual, etc and can't get any solution to work.

I think the problem has to do with "bundle install" as I'm getting a message that says SQLite 3.6.16 (at least) is needed.

Can someone provide a step-by-step how to update?

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade sqlite ? the current version is 3.7.5 on their site. You could also use macport (version 3.7.4) to upgrade it-- Either download it then run (tar xzf sqlite-3.7.5.tar.gz $ cd sqlite-3..5 $ ./configure $ make $ sudo make install) or via macport ($ sudo port selfupdate $ sudo port upgrade outdated)

Comment: As an alternative to Macport, try [brew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/). It is a **much** simpler mechanism for installing and upgrading software than Macport. Once you install brew, to install sqlite you would type `brew install sqlite`. It looks like Brew is installing 3.7.5

Comment: Also, before you go wildly installing software, check to make sure you don't already have it installed. try `sqlite3 --version` and/or `which sqlite3` to confirm that it is installed and which version you are using. Mac OS X comes with SQlite pre-installed so unless you've removed it, you should have it.

Comment: @sorens - brew seems nice, actually I want to test it, but afraid that it will make problem with MacPort also installed...

Comment: there is information on how to clear out installs with macports in the brew wiki and installation pages. also, when I switched over to using brew, i followed [this guide on uninstalling macports](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html). I'm not advocating that you go this route to solve your problem, but here is the documentation for when you want to try it out.

Comment: @oyo @sorens Thank you for your comments! "sqlite3 --version" gives 3.6.12. oyo, I followed your command line steps and all were successful, but when I run the "sqlite3 --version" I still get 3.6.12. Would "./configure -prefix=/usr/local" work?

Comment: doubtful. can you edit the original question to include the exact output you get when you run `bundle install` from within your rails directory?

Comment: !! `bundle install` works now and I was able to fire up the server.. I'll take it!

Comment: @sorens Thanks, not sure why `sqlite3 --version` still shows 3.6.12?

Comment: That's the version that I have. I am guessing you didn't actually go through with any of the installation/update steps. You don't need 3.7.5 sqlite. I am using 3.6.12 and it works great. Glad you were able to get it working.

Comment: @sorens Agreed, doesn't appear that any of the updates went through. In the future I'll try MacPorts.

Answer (score 3):

First check to which version of sqlite3 that want to upgrade to and figure out what the URL for the tar is. In following example I upgraded to version 3.6.18
Go to SQLite3 Download Page
Then as follows:

```
mkdir ~/src
cd ~/src
curl http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-3.6.18.tar.gz | tar xvfz
cd sqlite-3.6.18
autoconf
./configure –prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
# check what version of SQLite is installed
sqlite3 –version
# 3.6.18
which sqlite3
# /usr/local/bin/sqlite3
```

Comment: The answer was missing a space & hyphen after the "xvfz". It should read "tar xvfz -"